# Personal access token required despited added SSH key in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I added SSH key using [this instruction](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh). Despite it, a personal access token is required when I try to `git pull`. Is it normal? I can't have multiple accounts in Windows because of this issue.
The only difference with the instruction that my key name is specific, I added `config` file into ~/.ssh directory:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_some_tag
```

UPD: I also noticed that the problem occurs only if I `git clone https://...` but not when `git clone git@github.com:username/gitname.git`. Can somebody explain how it works?
UPD2: `git clone git@...` only worked for the first account but I can't `git clone git@...` using the second account. I'm trying `git clone` a private repo.

Comment: Using "git clone https://..." is *not* using ssh, so your ssh config will not be used. For why you can't use the same config on 2 accounts, it is likely you have only added your ssh key to one account. If you give some more details, we might be able to help you out.

Comment: @Randomhero thank you, it's actually enough information. For some reason I thought ssh keys are used for https connection too. Now it all works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above:

*Using "git clone https://..." is **not** using ssh, so your ssh config will not be used.*